# How do I use the returned variable from a method in another class in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method that returns a long and I want to be able to use it outside said method but I can't seem to figure this out... A little help?

Here's the method:

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

namespace API
{
    public class UserIDClass
    {
        protected string responseHeader = "";
        protected long id = 0;
        public long idMethod(string responseHeader, long id)
        {

            string[] bearerToken = responseHeader.Split(" ");
            var txtJwtIn = bearerToken[1];
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(txtJwtIn);
            var decodedToken = handler.ReadToken(txtJwtIn) as JwtSecurityToken;
            var sub = decodedToken.Subject;
            string[] subSplit = sub.Split("|");
            long goodId = Int64.Parse(subSplit[1]);
            if (goodId == id)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("goodId "+ goodId + "  = id " + id);
                }
                else {

                Console.WriteLine("goodId = " + goodId + " but the id you searched was " + id);

            return goodId;
        }


}}
```

and here's the code I'm instantiating the method in:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<ActionResult<User>> Get(long id)
        {
            var responseHeader = Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault();
            UserIDClass useridclass = new UserIDClass();
            useridclass.idMethod(responseHeader, id);
            var User = await _context.Users.FindAsync(id);    
            Console.WriteLine(goodId);
            return Ok(User);

        }
```

I want to be able to use the goodId long outside of that method but when I try to write it to the console in the get method I get "the name does not exist in your current context". I feel Like I'm missing something super simple here. I'm still learning so be ever so gentle :)

Comment: `var goodId = useridclass.idMethod(responseHeader, id);` ?

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From what I can gather with your code, it looks like when you instantiating the method, you should create a long variable that holds the output of the method idMethod. What it looks like is you are trying to access the long variable "goodId" but it's out of scope. I would try something like this.

```
long id = useridclass.idMethod(responseHeader, id);
```